# Ignore select before insert in JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

we declare some tables like this in JPA:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {

    public A() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "a")
    private Set<B> bs = new HashSet<>();
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "b")
public class B {

    public B() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_B_A"))
    private A a;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "c_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_B_C"))
    private C c;

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "C")
public class C {

    public C() {
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
}
```

now I wanna insert some record in the table, we know that value of c_id is 1, and we wanna insert a record in B without select from C.

we write this code now :

```
a = aRepository.find(a_id);
b = new B();
b.setCId(1);
a.setBs(b);
aRepository.save(a);
```

but JPA, before insert record, does a select on C and get all records from c by id ==1, how can I denied this select and tell to JPA just insert without select?

console log logged something like this:

```
""2018-02-06 16:08:44 - 
    select
        ...
    from
        c c_ 
    where
        c_.id=?
""2018-02-06 16:08:44 - 
    insert 
    into
        b
        (id, c_id, a_id) 
    values
        (null, ?, ?)
```

Answer (score 2):

To set C call getReference (e.g. getOne in JpaRepository) with the id like

```
a = aRepository.find(a_id);
b = new B();

C c = cRepository.getOne(1)
b.setC(c);

a.setBs(b);
aRepository.save(a);
```

With getReference aka getOne there will be no SQL statement it will just create a proxy object that you can assign to a.

Comment: If I read the specification correctly the JPA implementation is **allowed** to return a proxy without checking the database. So what actually happens is up to the database.

Comment: I meant "up to the JPA implementation".